# Store incoming URL in a session variable BEFORE the 301 rewrites kick in

Tags: .htaccess, session, redirect

combed the net and have found nothing specific. My question is, is the following at all possible and if yes, could somebody please give me a "tip" so that I may persue the issue further - thanks.

Basically I'm combiningg a few mini-websites into one and using 301 rewrites to redirect the old URLS. ie. rabbit.mytld, dog.mytld and cat.mytld will then all rewrite to pets.mytld in the future.

So far, so good - but, before the rewites kick in, I would like to store the incoming URL in a session variable passed to the website, so that I can then display a rabbit or dog or cat logo and have an alternative colour scheme so as not to confuse visitors who suddenly see a new website. Possible at all?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you still wanting to keep the URLs `rabbit.mytld` and `dog.mytld` etc?

Comment: Yes, these domians will still be active, just simply routed to the pets.mytld global site.

Comment: How do you redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean 301 "redirect" (not "rewrite")? You are "combining" these sites, so all SEO value is being transferred to `pets.mytld`.

You can't do much *before* the redirect occurs. You can't set a "session variable" (in terms of "PHP session" for instance) - since that happens much later in the request. You can perhaps set a cookie at the time of the redirect. But in both cases the cookie (or session) is being set on the source domain (eg. `rabbit.mytld`), not the target (`pets.mytld`). So any value being set will be lost by the time it gets to the target domain.

However, for SEO you don't want to do that anyway, as search engines won't be able to pick this up. Search engines don't use sessions or cookies. When a search engine visits `pets.mytld`, they just see your "default" page. Not *rabbit*, *dog* or *cat*. Consequently, they may discount the redirect for that reason.

Instead, you should have a unique URL at the target site to which you should be redirecting to. For example:

- `rabbit.mytld` to `pets.mytld/rabbit`
- `dog.mytld` to `pets.mytld/dog`
- `cat.mytld` to `pets.mytld/cat`

You could do this with the following directives in `.htaccess` at `rabbit.mytld`, `dog.mytld` etc.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.mytld [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://pets.mytld/%1 [R=302,L]
```

This grabs the first part of the requested domain name (eg. `rabbit`, `dog`, etc.) and passes this through to the target URL in place of the `%1` backreference.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect - only change it to a 301 when you are sure it's working OK - in order to avoid any browser caching issues whilst testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cats\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://pets.example.com/$1 [L, NC, R=301, CO=pets:cats:pets.example.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dogs\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://pets.example.com/$1 [L, NC, R=301, CO=pets:dogs:pets.example.com]
```

See more on [Apache cookie flag co](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co)